# Cannot link X11 xQuartz 2.7.1, no architecture amd64?

Tags: xcode, x11

I Cannot link X11 xQuartz 2.7.1, no architecture amd64???????

I have a simple program that uses X11.  it runs fine in an old xcode on an Intel Mac.

But now I have a mac Mini M1 and xCode cannot find a xquartz amd64 architecture.

I have done a bunch of -L /usr/opt/X11   linker control lines  but still no go.

Any ideas?   The xQuartz documentation is mum about what architecture it supports!

I *think* it is finding the right library path as NOW it doesn't complain about not finding the entry points like XCreateWindow, instead it complains about the wrong architecture.

Thanks,

grg

Answer (score 1):

There is a port of Xquartz to Apple Silicon - searching the web does give a few links

One I found https://github.com/XQuartz/XQuartz/issues/14#issuecomment-754400158 is by the person who maintains XQuartz

> Yeah, it works fine and has since very early in our bringup of Apple Silicon Macs. There just isn't a package available because nobody has taken over managing releases, so your best bet is to use MacPorts.

and from https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/native-x11-support-on-apple-silicon.2274198/

> X11 in MacPorts is functional and native on the M1. (I should know, I did some of the work to get it running.)

> sudo port install xorg

> MacPorts equivalent of Xquartz.app is X11.app.